# Python-SocketIO , Yoloface: Is there a possibility that a function call is blocking my main thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, flask, flask-socketio

I am working on a Flask Server with SocketIO. I emplemented an event handler and this is working fine (i implemented the client in a Adroid Studio Project). I can emit and receive Messages without any Problem.

I also want to use Yoloface for Facedetection and i am calling the function with scan_face(). I encountered a problem that scan_face() will only return the correct value for the first time i receive a scan_request from the Client. Everytime there is another scan_request from the client the function is not even called and if i try to use breakpoints to debug the breakpoints are skipped, scan_face() not called and the server continues to listen to the client

this is my output from the console:

```
flask run --host='0.0.0.0'
----- info -----
[i] Source of the camera:  0
[i] Path to output directory:  outputs/
###########################################################

==> Skipping create the outputs/ directory...
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://x.x.x.x:5000
 * Running on http://x.x.x.x:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
x.x.x.x - - [25/Mar/2024 23:29:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Client connected to default namespace
x.x.x.x - - [25/Mar/2024 23:29:04] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=iiua90AsbvoVBspJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
x.x.x.x - - [25/Mar/2024 23:29:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=iiua90AsbvoVBspJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
x.x.x.x - - [25/Mar/2024 23:29:04] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=iiua90AsbvoVBspJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
x.x.x.x - - [25/Mar/2024 23:29:04] "POST /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&sid=iiua90AsbvoVBspJAAAA HTTP/1.1" 200 -
check1
Received scan request: Scanne Person
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
200
227
254
[i] ==> # detected faces: 1
############################################################
value1
2gesichter
check2
person sent
2
check1
Received scan request: Scanne Person
check1
Received scan request: Scanne Person
```

This is where i call the scan_face() function:

```
@socketio.on('scan_request')
    def handle_scan_request(message):
        print('check1')
        print(f"Received scan request: {message}")
        scan_result = scan_face() # here i call the function which works only for the first time
        print('check2')
        if scan_result == 1:
            get_person_by_id()
        elif scan_result == 0:
            person_not_detected()
```

This is the whole code of my Eventhandler:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, leave_room, join_room, emit
from flask import request
from sqlalchemy import func
from flask_socketio import send
from yoloface import scan_face
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QEventLoop, QCoreApplication, QThread, pyqtSignal

db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
socketio = SocketIO(cors_allowed_origins="*")
last_sent_person_id = 1


def create_app():
    global last_sent_person_id

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    socketio.init_app(app)

    from models import Person

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def handle_request():
        return 'Successful Connection'

    @app.route('/api/persons', methods=['GET'])
    def get_all_persons():
        persons = Person.query.all()
        result = []
        for person in persons:
            result.append({
                'id': person.id,
                'first_name': person.first_name,
                'last_name': person.last_name,
                'last_seen': person.last_seen,
                'status': person.status,
                'notes': person.notes,
                'pronouns': person.pronouns,
                'appointment': person.appointment,
                'notRecognized': person.notRecognized,
                'notSeenInReminderPeriod': person.notSeenInReminderPeriod,
                'image': person.image
            })
        return jsonify(result)

    def delete_all_data():
        with app.app_context():
            db.session.query(Person).delete()
            db.session.commit()

    @app.route('/delete_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def delete_data():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            delete_all_data()
            return 'All data deleted successfully'
        else:
            return 'This endpoint accepts POST requests only'

    @app.route('/create_dummys', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def create_dummys():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            from dummy_data import create_dummy_data
            create_dummy_data()
            return 'Dummy data created successfully'
        elif request.method == 'GET':
            return 'This endpoint accepts POST requests only'

    @socketio.on('get_person_by_id')
    def get_person_by_id():
        global last_sent_person_id
        person = Person.query.filter_by(id=last_sent_person_id).first()

        if person:
            print("person sent")
            emit('person_data', {
                'id': person.id,
                'first_name': person.first_name,
                'last_name': person.last_name,
                'last_seen': person.last_seen,
                'status': person.status,
                'notes': person.notes,
                'pronouns': person.pronouns,
                'appointment': person.appointment,
                'notRecognized': 'False',
                'notSeenInReminderPeriod': person.notSeenInReminderPeriod,
                'image': person.image
            })

        else:
            emit('server_message', 'Person with ID 1 not found!', broadcast=True)

        last_sent_person_id += 1
        print(last_sent_person_id)

    @socketio.on('send_empty_person')
    def person_not_detected():
        emit('person_not_detected', {
            'id': 0,
            'first_name': 0,
            'last_name': 0,
            'last_seen': 0,
            'status': 0,
            'notes': 0,
            'pronouns': 0,
            'appointment': 0,
            'notRecognized': 'False',
            'notSeenInReminderPeriod': 'True',
            'image': 0
        })

    @socketio.on('connect')
    def handle_connect():
        print('Client connected to default namespace')
        emit('server_message', 'Willkommen beim WebSocket-Server!', broadcast=True)

    @socketio.on('disconnect')
    def handle_disconnect():
        print('Client disconnected from default namespace')

    @socketio.on('message')
    def handle_message(data):
        print('received message: ' + data)
        send(data, broadcast=True)

    @socketio.on('scan_request')
    def handle_scan_request(message):
        print('check1')
        print(f"Received scan request: {message}")
        scan_result = scan_face()
        print('check2')
        if scan_result == 1:
            get_person_by_id()
        elif scan_result == 0:
            person_not_detected()

    from namespace import PersonNamespace
    socketio.on_namespace(PersonNamespace('/persons'))

    return app
```

And this is the yoloface.py where de scan_face() function is defined (i changed the function from yoloface.py so that i can call it without the need of arguments)

```
import argparse
import asyncio
import sys
import os

from utils import *

SRC = 0
OUTPUT_DIR = 'outputs/'
MODEL_CFG = './cfg/yolov3-face.cfg'
MODEL_WEIGHTS = './model-weights/yolov3-wider_16000.weights'

#####################################################################
# print the arguments
print('----- info -----')
print('[i] Source of the camera: ', SRC)
print('[i] Path to output directory: ', OUTPUT_DIR)
print('###########################################################\n')

# check outputs directory
if not os.path.exists(OUTPUT_DIR):
    print('==> Creating the {} directory...'.format(OUTPUT_DIR))
    os.makedirs(OUTPUT_DIR)
else:
    print('==> Skipping create the {} directory...'.format(OUTPUT_DIR))

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(MODEL_CFG, MODEL_WEIGHTS)
net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)


def scan_face():
    wind_name = 'face detection using YOLOv3'
    cv2.namedWindow(wind_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    output_file = ''

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(SRC)

    value = None

    while True:

        has_frame, frame = cap.read()

        # Create a 4D blob from a frame.
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255, (IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT),
                                     [0, 0, 0], 1, crop=False)

        # Sets the input to the network
        net.setInput(blob)

        # Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
        outs = net.forward(get_outputs_names(net))

        # Remove the bounding boxes with low confidence
        faces = post_process(frame, outs, CONF_THRESHOLD, NMS_THRESHOLD)
        print('[i] ==> # detected faces: {}'.format(len(faces)))
        print('#' * 60)

        # initialize the set of information we'll displaying on the frame
        info = [
            ('number of faces detected', '{}'.format(len(faces)))
        ]

        for (i, (txt, val)) in enumerate(info):
            text = '{}: {}'.format(txt, val)
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, (i * 20) + 20),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, COLOR_RED, 2)


        cv2.imshow(wind_name, frame)

        value = len(faces)
        print("value" + str(value))

        if value == 0:
            print('0gesicht')
            break

        elif value == 0:
            print('1gesicht')
            break
        else:
            print('2gesichter')
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    if value == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

I tried a few things including multithreading but none of it works so that i can call scan_face() everytime i receive a scan request from the client.

I am out of ideas how i am able to call scan_face() consistently. Maybe i am missing something.
value = len(faces)

I thought that my flask Server is running on my main thread and that the call of the scan_face() function is blocking it but it still didn't work.

Also i thought that scan_face() may not be terminated in the right way so i tried to force the termination of scan_face() with sys.exit() but it still only worked the first time i called the function.

Comment: never ever put desktop GUI into a web server.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by that? I am pretty new to flask and sokcetio and i thought i didn't put any GUI into my web server.

Comment: opencv `imshow` is "desktop GUI". if you run your code on some server on the internet, that `imshow` window will not pop up on your own computer, but on the server... if it had a display attached to it, which it doesn't.

Comment: alright. Is there a way to call the function if a scan_request is received by the server?  I need the data of the return value of the scan_face function in my event-handler so i can decide what action comes next.

Comment: you should also not use or even import Qt. that too is "desktop GUI". if you accidentally left that import in your code, I must remind you of the [mre] article. you presented 220+ lines of code. that is a LOT and usually more than a MRE should need to demonstrate any issue. -- your issue *seems to* involve many different things. I find it very unlikely that anyone would be knowledgeable and willing to deal with all of those things in order to help you. it's on you to increase your chances. chances are generally low if almost a day has passed without anyone making progress on a question.